# AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds position using Xamarin.form Xaml

Tags: xaml, layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.form Xaml :When I am giving AbsoulteLayout layoutBounds(.5,.5,.5,.5) its coming on center but not for ios... and If I'm using (.75,.75,.5,.5) its coming on center for ios not for android in Xamarin form xaml page.....How to have same layoutBounds for both ios and android

Given Example:

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="#99000000"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                   
                    IsVisible="{Binding xyz}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

      <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="xyz"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Put your whole example. Without setting `Width/Height` I'm not able to see inner `AbsoluteLayout`. If I change inner `AbsoluteLayout` to `Frame` and set some background then I'm able to see inner content and it's placed in the center for both. Could you tell me how do you set size for inner `AbsoluteLayout`?

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy We are setting Height and Width manually using _HeightRequest/WidthRequest_ and dynamically adding that layout to inner Absolute Layout. Is there any way to achieve without using **OnPlatform** so that it will be generic for all platform.

Comment: If I set `WidthRequest/HeightRequest` to `50` on inner layout, I'm able to see this layout placed in the center with `.5,.5,.5,.5` values.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for replies.
I have resolved the problem related to center alignment of in absolute layout,   hope this is helpful

```
    <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"    IsVisible="{Binding ShowPopup}">
        <BoxView Color="#99000000" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
        <StackLayout x:Name="Popup" Padding="6" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, -1, -1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OnPlatform](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential_xaml_syntax/) to have different values on different platforms.

Eg:

```
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
      <OnPlatform.iOS>
        0, 20, 0, 0
      </OnPlatform.iOS>
      <OnPlatform.Android>
        0, 0, 0, 0
      </OnPlatform.Android>
      <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
        0, 0, 0, 0
      </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
    </OnPlatform>
  </ContentPage.Padding>
```

Modifying your code (*untested*) :

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="#99000000"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                   
                    IsVisible="{Binding xyz}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

      <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="xyz"                     
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
                     <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Rectangle">
                        <OnPlatform.iOS>
                              0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5
                        </OnPlatform.iOS>
                        <OnPlatform.Android>
                              0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
                        </OnPlatform.Android>
                        <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                              0, 0, 0, 0
                        </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                     </OnPlatform>
            </AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
      </AbsoluteLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: We are able to achieve the same layout using **OnPlatform** but is there any way to achieve without using this so that it will be generic for all platform.

Comment: There are things that are platform specific, like the top padding of iOS. You can't generalize everything.

Answer (score 0):

This way we can use platforms directives for `LayoutBounds` in `AbsoluteLayout` for every controls

```
<Label AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
  <Label.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Rectangle" iOS="..." Android="..." /> 
    </Label.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
</Label>
```